# How do I emulate a button press in web scraping?

Tags: go, web-scraping

Hello I am using [`colly`](https://github.com/gocolly/colly) to scrape my university's classes. The web page is simple enough

```
<form id="rngID" method="post" action="../../../SOME_REALLY_LONG_PATH">

<input type="hidden" name="rngID_hf_0" id="rngID_hf_0">
            <label for="user">User:</label>
            <input type="text" maxlength="20" value="" name="user" class="required valid">
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" maxlength="20" value="" name="password" class="required valid">
            <input type="hidden" id="js" value="1" name="js" class="valid">
<script>
/*<![CDATA[*/
                document.getElementById("js").value = "1"
/*]]>*/
</script>
<input type="submit" class="btn-blue valid" name="login" id="rngID+2" value="Ingresar">
</form>
```

I find myself needing to interact with the website's contents. I understand I have the underlying  objects associated to the HTML file recieved, but I am struggling to find how to trigger the submit action. Moreover I am unsure how to set the html input values with colly (username and password).

Can this not be done in colly? It seems to have good cookie management which fits in what I'm looking fo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colly doesn't resolve/render the HTML DOM to the same degree as a web browser in a few ways, but the most notable is that **it doesn't interpret and run JavaScript**. So there is no direct way to emulate button presses with it.

However, forms can be submitted through post requests and goColly supports this with the Post method for a collector.

Comment: Alright, so I can't emulate a button press. Could I somehow post the form data?  Colly does have a POST method implemented. I understand I have to add the key-values for `"user","password"`, and `"js"`. To what URL would I be posting? I've tried posting to the `action` path but I get a `Forbidden` error message.

Comment: @FemtoComm you'll need to find out what *exactly* is sent to the server using your browsers' network analysis tools. Many websites block requests sent without User-Agent header, but it's really specific to the site you're trying to do this with.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @xarantolus. goColly supports posting so I managed to login with the help of that and the network tools you mentioned (on chrome F12 -> Network Tab -> record Network log -> export HAR)